# Apply custom permission template automatically for sonarqube new project report using sonar-runner

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1

How to configure  sonar.projectKey under sonar-project.properties so that we can get apply custom permission template for new project report automatically.
Does anyone try that?
I was trying all type of combination with project key in sonarqube permission template and sonar-runner properties file. But couldn't achieve the result.

Does sonar permission template really support this from sonar-runner.

Below are screenshot attached to the link for my use case:

[I have created mfg-desktop permission template and there is also present a default template provided by sonar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVPUu.png)

[When I checked under project permission, I found that default permission template is getting applied in each time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYxve.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new permission Template and assign the regex to the *Project Key Pattern*.

For example: 
Regex :
(prod)-\w+

It will apply the template to the new projects created with *Project Key* starting with 'prod-'. Sonar needs the key of the new projects to 'fully' match the regex of the permission template key. Using * might not work.

Then link the desired permissions of the users/group on the template. Also make sure the Global Permissions for the users/group are also set appropriately else permissions wont work.

Additional Info: All projects will still be visible to all users. Make your project 'Private' to make it visible only to the required group.
This works on CE v7.6

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing to do on the `sonar-project.properties` side.

As described [in the docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization#Authorization-PermissionTemplatesforDefaultProjectPermissions), set up your permission template with a project key pattern regular expression. All new projects with keys that match the regex will have that permission template applied.

For example, if in the "Manufacturing Group" template I set my *Project Key Pattern* to:

```
 mfg-*
```

and analyze a new project with a key of `mfg-extrusion`, then the "Manufacturing Group" template will be applied. And when I analyze `front-office-billing` for the first time, it will not.

Comment: Will this work with sonarqube 5.6.4 LTS? I using currently this version. I have tried those above mentioned steps and I found that it won't apply the permission template for newly created project which is defined in permission template project key. It always applys default permission template which is provided by sonar.

Comment: @anandkrv you should edit your question to include what you've tried (screenshots are good...) and the result you got from it.

Comment: I have attached screenshot above as a link. you can refer that.

Comment: It worked for me! I have rechecked the regex for project key.